# EF Code First Add-Migration -> Update-Database doesn't see explicit Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

For some reason, on 2 of our computers with the latest version of EF 6 installed if you do an Add-Migration on the project it will add it, you can do whatever you need to, to the migration, but when you do Update-Database it doesn't see the migrations ("No pending explicit migrations") and no other machine will see that migration either.

Any other computer with exactly the same course code can generate a migration without issue and Update-Database just works.

Ideas?

Comment: Are these all pointing to different databases? If they are pointing at the same database, then that would be the expected behavior.

Comment: Same database and there's no code source stomping going on. It's just ignoring any new migrations on 2 computers while the rest can create migrations at will that work just fine.

Comment: So you have multiple developers with the same code base pointing at the same database. If Dev 1 creates and applies a migration and the other developers refresh their code they shouldn't need to run a migration. Or are you talking about simultaneous different changes?

Comment: See this on migrations in team settings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn481501

Comment: I understand that, but that isn't what's happening. ALL machines have EXACTLY the same code. ALL migrations have been applied to the target database without any issue. However, if these 2 computers then try and add a subsequent migration it will not apply and will be ignored but the others on the same code with the same applied migrations will work just fine.

Comment: Even more fun, if the second computer that does work creates the migration then syncs code via git to the first machine that doesn't, and the first machine does Update-Database it gets the update and it works fine.

Comment: On the non-working computer try "update-database -Script  –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase" and see what it produces. Look at the context key it produces to check migrations and see if that matches what is in the __MigrationHistory table of the database in question.

Comment: Running that, everything was identical. Immediately after that it now works properly. Very very very strange.